# guitar amp experienced over-voltage

Tags: amplifier, damage

Disclaimer: I am not an electrical engineer, I made a mistake which left a piece of equipment in what feels like it should be a salvageable state, but I don't know where to start correcting it.

So, I have an old guitar practize amplifier, which is a [Blackstar Fly](https://blackstaramps.com/product/fly-3/), and used it with an incorrect supply. It was providing a 20v supply, when the amp requires a 6v supply. There's a loud crackle, and amp is unresponsive.

I then tried providing battery power. The amp shows some signs of life, but I'm not hearing any signal from the input.

The signs of life are:

- On turning on the power, there is a crackling sound.
- The power indicator light turns on at full brightness, then fades to about 20% brightness in around a second.

So I know I've damaged the amp, it doesn't seem completely dead. What steps can I do to diagnose the issue, and is it likely to be a repair (or component replacement) that I could do myself?

Note: I managed to find a [very detailed breakdown](http://www.midboost.com/workbench/blackstar-fly-3) of this specific amplifier, including circuit diagrams etc. but it doesn't seem at all focussed on troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

The answer below is based on an assumption of that the info shown on the webpage you linked is accurate.

In the supply regulator [subcircuit](http://www.midboost.com/workbench/blackstar-fly-3-pt2), the regulator IC, NCP57152, accepts a maximum input of 18 VDC. Since you applied 20 VDC which is outside the IC's guaranteed limits, you might have fried the IC which may possibly result in a shorted input-output, causing the rest of the amplifier circuit to be exposed to 20 VDC. So the entire amplifier circuit have dead.

For example, the power amp section which consists of a class-D amp, PAM8304, is supposed to be supplied from 5 VDC. According to its datasheet, the maximum that can be applied is 6.5 VDC. If the main regulator IC is dead and the input-output is shorted then the entire PA section should be dead.

Similarly, the two op-amp ICs I saw in the circuit, TLC2272 and MV358, accept a maximum supply voltage of 8 VDC and 6 VDC, respectively. Again, if the regulator shorted the input-output after its death then all the subcircuits employing these op-amps should also be dead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It's not looking good, is it?

Comment: @AJFaraday I'm afraid not.